# How to open a PDF from an Android app (in a separate PDF viewer app)

Tags: android, pdf

The goal is to be able to add a PDF file to the "assets" folder of an app, and let the user open that PDF in a PDF app (ezPDFReader, Adobe Reader, etc). This is not entirely straightforward as the PDF first needs copying from the assets folder onto the device storage. If the device has no PDF viewer app on it, we need to show a warning message and direct them to the Play Store to download one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me. It's a class called `PdfHandler` and here's how you use it - just put the pdf file in the assets folder. It will open it in a PDF viewer app if one is available, and if not show a warning message and direct the user to the Adobe Reader Play Store entry.

```
PdfHandler pdf = new PdfHandler(this);
pdf.openPdf("document.pdf");
```

The PdfHandler class. You should move text resources into Android string resources.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Handles the opening of PDF files, using whatever app the user has installed to view PDFs
 * If no PDF app installed, shows a warning and directs them to appropriate Store listing
 */
public class PdfHandler {

    public PdfHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void openPdf(String filename) {
        if (isPdfAppAvailable()) {
            copyPdfAndOpenIt(filename);
        } else {
            showPdfWarning();
        }
    }

    private void copyPdfAndOpenIt(String filename) {
        try {
            File file = copyPdfFromAssetsToStorage(filename);
            startPdfIntent(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("PdfHandler", "Error handling the PDF file", e);
        }
    }

    private File copyPdfFromAssetsToStorage(String filename) throws Exception {
        String tempFilename = "temp.pdf";
        AssetManager is = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = is.open(filename);
        String outFilename = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + tempFilename;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(tempFilename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return new File(outFilename);
    }

    private void copy(InputStream fis, FileOutputStream fos) throws IOException {
        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
            fos.write(b, 0, i);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPdfAppAvailable() {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void startPdfIntent(File file) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showPdfWarning() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Please install an app to view PDF file");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Install", getButtonListener());
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.setTitle("PDF Viewer");
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener getButtonListener() {
        return new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    goToGooglePlayStoreEntry();
                }
            };
    }

    private void goToGooglePlayStoreEntry() {
        context.startActivity(getAppListingIntent());
    }

    private Intent getAppListingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String pdfAppPackageName = "com.adobe.reader";
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + pdfAppPackageName));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return intent;
    }

    private Context context;

}
```

Comment: +1.  Very useful.  A nice enhancement would be the option to cache files, so that they need not be copied every time, in situations where you'd like faster loading and less battery consumption, and are not so worried about persistent storage usage.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Its really help full to others to open pdf outside application. can you please suggest me How I can open pdf inside my app without action intent.

Answer (score 1):

The PdfHandler posted by Ollie C works perfectly, but it is a bit slow because it copies the PDF first from assets to storage before it can be opened. Opening the PDF will be faster if you use a ContentProvider instead.

Note that if your filename is MyPdf.pdf, the file should be assets/public_pdfs/MyPdf.pdf.mp3. The path public_pdfs is to only export the pdfs you really want to export, and the .mp3 extension is to prevent compression.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider android:authorities="my.app.PdfContentProvider" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:name="my.app.PdfContentProvider">
</provider>
```

**Opening a PDF**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://my.app.PdfContentProvider/" + filename);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");

startActivity(intent);
```

**PdfContentProvider.java**

```
public class PdfContentProvider extends ContentProvider
{
  private static final String PDFPATH = "public_pdfs/";

  @Override
  public String getType(Uri uri)
  {
    return "application/pdf";
  }

  @Override
  public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
    String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();

    if (file_name == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try
    {
      afd = am.openFd(PDFPATH + file_name + ".mp3");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return afd;
  }

  private final static String[] COLUMNS = {OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE};

  @Override
  /**
   * This function is required for it to work on the Quickoffice at Android 4.4 (KitKat)
   */
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
  {
    if (projection == null)
    {
      projection = COLUMNS;
    }

    String[] cols = new String[projection.length];
    Object[] values = new Object[projection.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String col : projection)
    {
      if (OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME.equals(col))
      {
        cols[i] = OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
        values[i++] = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      }
      else if (OpenableColumns.SIZE.equals(col))
      {
        cols[i] = OpenableColumns.SIZE;
        values[i++] = AssetFileDescriptor.UNKNOWN_LENGTH;
      }
    }

    cols = copyOf(cols, i);
    values = copyOf(values, i);

    final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(cols, 1);
    cursor.addRow(values);
    return cursor;
  }

  private static String[] copyOf(String[] original, int newLength)
  {
    final String[] result = new String[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
    return result;
  }

  private static Object[] copyOf(Object[] original, int newLength)
  {
    final Object[] result = new Object[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, 0, newLength);
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreate()
  {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
  {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LoginProgress task = new LoginProgress();
task.execute(Pdffile);




public class LoginProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected Context applicationContext;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(applicationContext,
                    "Data Loading", "Loading .....", true);
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // video();
            LoadUrl(Pdffile);
            return null;
        }
        private void LoadUrl(File Pdffile) {
            try {
                u r stuff here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```