# How to display pdf document asynchronously in android?

Tags: android

I am displaying a pdf document in my android application. For that I followed from the link [How to open a PDF from an Android app (in a separate PDF viewer app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995915/how-to-open-a-pdf-from-an-android-app-in-a-separate-pdf-viewer-app). My pdf document size is of 30mb. So it is taking time to display it. Hence I need to display it asynchronously. I am new to asynchronous tasks. Please give me some idea on how to display the pdf asynchronously.

[image]

Comment: you can use progressDialog

Comment: Hi please can you give some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not you the one who open this pdf. You open it with other application, so if rendering speed is low, the only thing you can do is select other app for openeing it. It's not your responsibility and in your case it's not related to asynchronous tasks at all. I think it will be usefull for you to read about [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) first of all and get some more knowlege abour Android framework and how it works.

Comment: Ok thank you. Actually I kept a button and when I click on that button the pdf will open with whatever software the mobile has to open pdf docs. But since my pdf is of large size when I click on the button I want to show that the doc is still loading. For that how can i do?

Comment: If you are using external app you can's do thing like that, it depends ONLY from external app. Right after button click your app is minimized and can't show anything. So there is no solution for your question and you just need to leave it as is. Also lot's of external readers are show progress bars while loading big pdf files.

Comment: @user1448108 BTW if my answer is helpfull and/or it answer your question you can upvote and/or check it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

use ProgressDialog as follow

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_PDF.this, "Loading",
                "Please wait", true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Toast.makeText(Activity_PDF.this, description,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
    // used to read PDF files from docs.google.com
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + stPdfLink);
```

Comment: hi I kept in weview as the example which u shown. But it is displaying the message. Please once see the image I kept in the question.

Comment: can u please tell me how to keep progrees bar for the code which I have done from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995915/how-to-open-a-pdf-from-an-android-app-in-a-separate-pdf-viewer-app