# Android: how to load pdf within app?

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I have:
First goal: figure out how to **load a PDF from the internet and display it whithin my app**
Second (maybe more complex) goal: **download a pdf and display OFFLINE within my app**

I looked for some solution on stackoverflow and on the Internet but I can't figure out **how to implement it**

For example I found Mupdf and the source code of some PDF viewer for Android but I'm quite confused: why is so difficult to display a "simple PDF"? Is there any Java library that will do it without incorporate external source code etc.?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079257/1218762

Comment: what type of pdf data you open that i mean base64?

Comment: @Mahesh I have no Idea. My goal is to download some PDF from the internet and show them in my app. I suppose the type is the "standard one",that is,the most common used

Comment: where you store your pdf file in memory card?

Comment: (with "where" do you mean in WHAT DIRECTORY? Actually I haven't made id,but I think as many apps do in a folder called "myApp")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some libraries and sdk.

This might help you

http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/